# Batch script to check until the url is up

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, while-loop, wget

I need a batch script where I can loop until the server is up. I could find a bash script of similar kind

```
while ! curl http://localhost:8080/wd/hub/status &>/dev/null; do :; done
```

I wrote a while loop for batch file can be of this kind

```
:while1
if ! wget http://localhost:8080 (
    echo down
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
    goto :while1
)
```

but its not working. Can anyone help in this issue..

Comment: batch is not object orientated. read `if /?`. Does `wget` (I don't have it) give you a reliable `%errorlevel%`?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    :while1
    wget http://localhost:8080
    if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
            echo down
            ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
            goto :while1
    )
```

I've just rewritten your error check to use my standard why of doing it.

Comment: Instead of `ping` to establish a delay you could also use the `timeout` command...